# "Package installer has stopped working" after updating to COS13/Marshmallow

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, system-error, oneplus-one

I have a **OnePlus One**, never rooted or modified the OS. Today I updated the OS from YOG7DAS2K1 (COS12.1) --> ZNH0EAS26M (COS13) via *OTA incremental update zip* from *Recovery (stock)*.

I wiped cache and user data from Recovery after update.

Phone seems to be fine so far, except this:

Whenever I *sideload* an APK, although the installed app works fine, an error message pops up at the end.

> "Unfortunately, Package Installer has stopped"

I tried wiping cache, rebooting, reinstalling those apps, but the error appears anyway.

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Here is another Q&A for a "Package installer has stopped working" error (in OOS3): https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162129/package-installer-has-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-oxygenos-3-1-4-marshma. I hope it helps some people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to reproduce this problem. It simply solved itself after changing the Cyanogen themes a few times.